# Have any astronauts ever abused drugs in space?

Tags: medical, astronaut-lifestyle, policy

I know from a few previous questions that some pretty strong drugs are available aboard different spacecraft and the ISS. Have any officials ever determined, on record, that drugs have been abused?

---

To clarify, by abused, I mean taken when not needed or more taken than needed.

For more information about drug abuse, see the [National Institute on Drug Abuse](http://www.easyread.drugabuse.gov/drugs-of-abuse.php).

Comment: Unless it caused a notably public danger to mission, vehicle, or crew, I doubt very much any such determination would ever be made public.  Crew health information is highly restricted.

Comment: It is the USA National Institute on Drug Abuse. The USA is not the world.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco True, but the US National Institute on Drug Abuse is relevant to NASA and other US astronauts. It doesn't really matter anyway because I linked it for information, not as supporting evidence of any kind.

Comment: Related: [Illegal Drugs Found Again at NASA Spaceport](http://www.space.com/11128-nasa-kennedy-space-center-cocaine.html)

Comment: Related: http://arstechnica.com/the-multiverse/2016/08/an-anecdotal-history-of-space-and-booze/

Answer (score 6):

From the technical definition of drugs, and your definition of abuse I can say I've been told of alcohol 'abuse' on the ISS. Abuse is a strong word, though; a celebratory drink was had when there was a crew change a while back; not what I would call abuse but it was 'taken when not needed'. There's even a picture out there on the internet somewhere of the crews at the time of the changes with the bottle! (I believe it was cognac.)

Comment: If you're referring to the Russians, it was not determined to be abuse on record. There's even a report that supposedly a Russian doctor prescribed the celebratory drink because of the "atmosphere" in the tight quarters.

Comment: And yes, abuse is a strong word. I chose it because if an official used that word it would be a serious incident.