# Psychotropes study in microgravity

Tags: microgravity, experiment

Alcohol seems to have been taken and consumed in space (not so sure about the ISS, but definitely on Mir).

Is this the only psychotrope substance that has been tried in space ?
Is there any formal study of the effect of such substances in microgravity ?

I'm especially interested in humans experiments, but animal ones are welcome too.

Comment: Related (but definitely distinct): https://space.stackexchange.com/q/2443/58